# How to force an attribute that is bound to a function to refresh

Tags: angularjs

When an angular attribute is bound to a property of a controller/scope, it automatically updates when that property changes. How can I get an attribute that is bound to a method of the controller/scope to change?

For example, let's say I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="vm.isInSet(vm.results.selectedRoles, role.id)"/>
```

When `vm.results` changes, I would like `ng-checked` to be updated, i.e. `vm.isInSet` should be called again. Or if I need to call some kind of explicit method to make all the elements on the page refresh, that would be fine too. I tried `$scope.$apply()`, but got the "$digest already in progress" error, so the digest cycle is already happening.

Comment: to avoid the `$digest already in progress` error you can use `$timeout` without a delay, it will set the contents of your callback to execute after the next $digest.  Not sure if this is a solution to your problem though.

Comment: use watch, very basic question, please explore more

Comment: @AliAdravi, $scope.$watch is to run some code when a variable changes; that is not what I am looking for. I am looking to have a binding to a function refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

**$watch helps to listen for $scope changes**

This is how you create your own watches. $watch service helps you to run some code when some value attached to the $scope has changed. It is rarely used, but sometimes is helpful. For instance, if you want to run some code each time 'myVar' changes, you could do the following:

```
function MyController($scope) {

    $scope.myVar = 1;

    $scope.$watch('myVar', function() {
        alert('hey, myVar has changed!');
    });

    $scope.buttonClicked = function() {
        $scope.myVar = 2; // This will trigger $watch expression to kick in
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$apply / $digest not running the vm.isInSet func, the user action does...

because ng-checked is a boolean verifier so you can move the logic from the html to the anguler directive/controller, i.e.:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="vm.states"/>

$scope.$watch('vm.results',function(newVal){
   vm.state = vm.isInSet(...);
});
```

if you have multiple checkbox's so you may use an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="vm.states[role.id]"/>

$scope.$watch('vm.results',function(newVal){
   vm.state[..] = vm.isInSet(...);
});
```